# Measures on Iwasawa decomposition

Tags: representation-theory

In the following I present two results, which look very similar, but require different proofs. I'd like to know why the second result doesn't admit the same proof as the first.

> **Lang $SL_2$ p39:** Let $P$, and $K$ be closed subgroups of $G$ such that $G=PK$. Assume that the map $$(p,k) \mapsto pk$$ gives a topological isomorphism (not group iso). Assume that $G$ and $K$ are unimodular. Then $dx = dpdk$
>
> Proof: Indeed there exists a left invariant measure on $G/K$, and $G/K$ is $P$-isomorphic to $P$ itself as a transformation space, under left translation. Hence  this measure is a Haar measure on P.

Now compare the preceding result with the following:

> **Lang $SL_2$ p40:** Assume that $P$ can be expressed as a product, $P = AN$ where $A, N$ are closed unimodular subgroups and $A$ normalizes $N$, i.e. $ana^{-1} \in N$ for $a \in A$ and $n\in N$. In other words, the map of $A \times N \to P$ given by $$(a,n) \mapsto an$$ is a topological isomorphism. Then $dp = dadn$
>
> Proof: The measure $dadn$ is clearly left invariant under A. Let $n_1 \in N$. $$\int_A\int_Nf(n_1an)dnda=\int_A\int_Nf(aa^{-1}n_1an)dnda.$$ But $a^{-1}n_1a \in N$ so we can cancel it in the inner integral by left invariance of the Haar measure on N. This proves our assertion.

Questions:

1) Why can't we simply show in the second case that $N = P/A$. This was done in the first proof even without knowing that $P$ normalized $K$.

2) We see that in both cases we need to prove left invariance of the group corresponding to the inner integral (the left invariance of the group corresponding to the outer integral is assumed in the hypothesis). My question is why. I would only expect that the invariance in the following sense would be necessary: $$f(an) \mapsto f(an_1n),$$ i.e. with the left multiplication acting exactly left to the integrating variable. This would be trivial because it is in the assumption.

Comment: In the second case, the intersection of the two subgroups might be too large to give the topological isomorphism needed in order to repeat the proof from the first case.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I'll will extend the quote a little bit.

Comment: This looks strange. Clearly the assumptions are not enough to get an isomorphism (consider $P = PP$). If he meant to include that they should intersect trivially, I suppose the missing part is the assumptions either of the subgroups being closed, or of some of the groups being unimodular (but now we are getting into details I am not familiar with).

Comment: Yup, you are right. I'm sorry, I thought I had copied that assumption as well.

Comment: Ok, then the only possibility I can see is if the product of unimodular groups need not be unimodular itself.

Comment: Hmm. I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the first case, you use the unimodularity of $G$. Since $P$ is not unimodular, you cannot argue the same way in the second case.

2) Let me answer as follows. The two theorems, as you mention, are similar: they both strive to express a Haar integral on a group as a double integral on two subgroups. However, their hypotheses are different, and this changes their proofs dramatically. Namely, the second one has an easy proof: you just transfer the product measure on $A\times N$ to $P$ and make use of the normalization assumption. Since you do not have this assumption in the first case, the proof is not so easy: you first need to deduce (by Theorem 1 on p. 37) the existence of a measure on the factor space $G/K$ and then transfer this measure to $P$; it is with respect to this measure on $P$ that the integral formula expressed by $\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}p\,\mathrm{d}k$ holds.